# Collector - Related tables and default filling of field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-collector

Have a polygon feature class with a related table in collector.

Is there a way for when a new record is added in the table for a field (area) to be automatically calculated from the features geometry?

The features will be edited over time and I want to be able to store the current area in the table of when the record was created to perform a calculation later on.

Comment: Have you checked to see if ArcGIS Field Maps can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is currently not available in Collector, and if you want it to be added feel free to post an idea on the [ArcGIS Ideas](https://community.esri.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/arcgis-ideas?id=087E0000000CxnlIAC) page.